# Using 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' with an Inner Join in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to get my insert query to run as i am receiving the error

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1-13951' for key 'virtuemart_product_id'
```

I have read about using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but being new to this i am not sure how exactly to fit it into my query, or whether this is the best way to achieve my insert? This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO jos_virtuemart_product_medias (`virtuemart_media_id`, `virtuemart_product_id`)
SELECT `virtuemart_media_id`, `virtuemart_product_id` 
FROM `jos_virtuemart_medias` 
INNER JOIN `jos_virtuemart_products` ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`jos_virtuemart_medias`.`file_url`, '/', -1), ".", 1),"-",1) = `jos_virtuemart_products`.`product_sku` WHERE 1
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Your `join` condition is way too complicated.  I think you have a more fundamental problem with your data structure.  (You should learn about junction tables.)

Comment: You should always `JOIN`  `ON` an indexed field. If you go on this way, it will get slow first and deadlock later. Regarding your problem, try `INSERT INTO ... ( SELECT ... ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field=newvalue`